# How to mock one-way binding parameters with $controller decorator?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

I am writing tests for a directive's controller whose startup logic requires some one-way bound parameters to be defined. I am facing difficulties passing one-way bound parameters to the mocked controller. text-bound parameters are passed without difficulty.

*NOTE: In the following code, I skip module injections and other irrelevant parts of the code*

Here is the directive's definition with two types of parameters:

```
function DummyDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: 
      oneWay: '&',
      text: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
    controller: 'GreatController',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
function GreatController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.treasure = '';

    activate();

    function activate() {
      vm.treasure = fantastic(vm.oneWay);
    }

    function fantastic(crap) {
      if(crap.stack) return 'gold';
    }
}
```

As for the test:

```
  var controller, $rootScope, $scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    controller = _$controller_(
      'GreatController',
      {$scope: $scope},
      {text: 'toGoodToBeTrue',
       oneWay: {
         stack: 'lotsOfIt',
       }
      }
    );
  }));

  it('should do the job', function(){
    expect(controller.treasure).toBe('gold');
  });
```

While `text` is properly passed to $controller, `oneWay` is undefined and the test fails. I have also tried to pass it a function returning an object to no avail. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller) does not cover one-way bound parameters. Would you know how to do this without testing the directive and passing parameters as markup? In general I like to keep my tests focused and test directives and their controllers separately.

Comment: `onWay` or `oneWay`? You have misspelled that variable

Comment: Sharp eye! The spelling mistake was corrected and the question remains

Comment: You know the one-way binding symbol is `<`, not `&`, right?

Comment: You also have an unclosed string at `.toBe('gold);`

Comment: Seems to be working fine here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/kQihnl8S7pYqgvnVI8Zq?p=preview

Comment: @Phil I should have been more specific: I am working on angular 1.4 so '<' binding is not available. Yout plunker works indeed. I will dig it farther and try to find what goes wrong in my code

Comment: @TristanHamel but the `&` binding is not one-way either. `&` is the expression binding.

Answer (score 0):

What if make oneWay optional, adding question mark to its definition:

```
oneWay: '&?'
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. Still, it would be preferable to write tests which do not need the code to be modified. Plus, what if this parameter is actually not optional?